# Force PHP to read a ZipFile entry with a CRC error

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm attempting to read a zip file in PHP that I know has a CRC error. Unfortunately, it looks like I can only get 31 bytes of the file to read. Using just `$zip->getFromName()` gives no errors but just reads 31 bytes

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("path/to/corrupted.zip");

// $contents will become just 31 bytes
$contents = $zip->getFromName("file/in/zip.txt");
```

Trying to read from the stream `$zip->getStream()` will give a CRC error, and again will only read 31 bytes

```php
$fp = $zip->getStream("file/in/zip.txt");

$contents = "";
while (!feof($fp)) {
    // Gives the error "fread(): Zip stream error: CRC error in ..."
    // Using 1 instead of 2 still only reads 31 bytes but gives no error
    $contents .= fread($fp, 2);
}

fclose($fp);
```

So, is there any way I could ignore this CRC error, and read the file anyways?

A little background: my website pre-processes .jar files users upload before they're downloaded by others. Users will occasionally upload a valid .jar file with CRC errors in an attempt to deter people from decompiling it. However, I still want to be able to pre-process these files for download.

I have a different pre-processor written in Python, and I was able to pretty easily disable the CRC check by modifying the zipfile library and [commenting out the line that does the crc check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/zipfile.py#L1042.). Is there any easy way I could do a similar thing in PHP without needing to make my own ZipFile library? I suppose worst case that's what I'll need to do.

Comment: Unrelated: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: To answer your question: I doubt it. Perhaps you could call out to Python so you can use the modified Python library.